# New url and server for a Magento web application

Tags: magento-1.9, url, migration, canonical

I use same magento application and database (like copy and paste) on another server(eg. a development server). It seens like a succeed implementing to the new server, but possibly because I have hardcoded

```
 <reference name="head">
 <action method="addLinkRel">
 <rel>canonical</rel>
 <href>www.oldsite.com</href>
 </action>
 </reference>
```

in the home page layout xml, not matter which url I use, it will redirect to the old site (eg. oldsite.com) like 127.0.0.1/newsite redirects to oldsite.com, 127.0.0.1/newsite/admin to oldsite.com/admin.I have changed both basic urls in database to 127.0.0.1/newsite, but nothing help. Could it be the canonical link or something else? If it is canonicall link , how can I change it, when I cannot login to the admin?

Comment: Please clear cash in var folder & also truncate all log tables in database

Answer (score 0):

You need to change all the rows in the table core_config_data where the path is web/secure/base_url and web/unsecure/base_url to the url you are using on your development server.